# Histogram with normal curve and error bars in R

Tags: r, histogram, data-science, graphing, errorbar

```
    #import data
    data = diameters$V1
    error = .005 #mm

    #make histogram
    h <- hist(data, breaks = "FD", density = 10,
              col = "lightblue", xlab = "Diameter", main = "Overall") 

    # Make normal curve
    xfit <- seq(min(data), max(data), length = 40) 
    yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)) 
    yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(data) 

    #Draw normal curve
    lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expectation:**

Is it possible to add error bars to the histogram using the value of +/- error without any external libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to draw them with the `arrows()` function:

```
## Create a histogram from random data
> hist(sample(runif(100)))
> arrows(x0 = 0.15, y0 = 11, x1 = 0.15, y1 = 13, code = 3, length = 0.05, angle = 90)
```

`x0` and `x1` specify the start and finish x coordinates (for a straight vertical line, keep them the same)

`y0` and `y1` specify the start and finish y coordinates e.g the length of the line to draw.

`code = 3` tells R to draw a double sided 'arrow', `angle = 90` makes the 'arrow' a flat line and `length = 0.05` specifies how wide the error bars should be.

[image]

See  `?arrows` for more details.